# Intern and client paths in version 1.1.0

Tags: intern

I noticed with release 1.1.0 that modules are not considered siblings of `intern` anymore.  For example, I used to be able to run something like `http://localhost/intern/client.html?config=myproject/tests/config` but it appears to try to attempt to fetch it from `http://localhost/intern/myproject/tests/config.js` instead as of previously `http://localhost/myproject/tests/config.js`.

Is this intentional?  Also, I tried to prepend `../myproject/tests/config` but it still apears to be fetching it relative to `intern`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you now have to install the intern using npm inside the project that contains the code you are testing. The intern is not a sibling of the tested project(s) anymore, but it is now located in subdirectory node_modules/intern of your tested project.

Comment: Yes, I was pointed to the release notes as well, which make this clear: https://github.com/theintern/intern/wiki/Changelog#since-10