# What are package paths in Intern config file relative to?

Tags: intern

In the Intern config file (default-conf.js, etc.), there's a packages section for the loader:

```
packages: [ { name: 'intern-selftest', location: '.' } ]
```

It specifies relative paths to each package.  But what are those paths relative to?

1. the directory node is run from
2. the location of the config file
3. the location of client.html / runner.js (i.e. the intern directory)
4. somewhere else?

The runsauce.sh works for me but in that case, node is run from the intern directory.  (A related question: does node need to be run from a certain directory?)

I've seen [Intern and client paths in version 1.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141394/intern-and-client-paths-in-version-1-1-0); not sure if that's still necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The paths are relative to `loader.baseUrl`, which in Intern 1.3 by default is the current working directory (command-line) or two levels above the client.html (browser).

Comment: Does this mean that if we wish to change the default `loader.baseUrl` we will have to dynamically configure it for it to work in both node and browser?

Comment: Yes, if you need to have a non-default directory configuration, and want to run Intern in all 4 possible ways (Node.js client, browser client, runner unit tests, runner functional tests) you will typically have to change the value depending upon the runtime environment. If you don’t plan on ever loading the browser client directly then you can always set it to a path that works in Node.js and it will work in the other 3 scenarios.